# Serial port on Raspberry Pi 3 with .Net Core

Tags: c#, serial-port, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to use the onboard UART on a Raspberry Pi 3 on Windows 10 IoT with .Net Core 2.0.

I referenced the System.IO.Ports (4.5.0-preview1-25914-04) NuGet package in a .NET Core 2.0 Console app but the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() function gives me only a strange name (ďżżďżżăŞč˝¨ě¬č»­  ă¤€č…žă¨č˝¨ĺ«č…łéŞ€čş„  ă¨¸č˝¨ç»č…łă¨ č˝¨ęŞ­č…‡    ě¬č»­  ě¬¨č»­ě‡č…˘ă¨¸č˝¨ŕ«č…Źă¨‚é„»  á¬€č…ž ă¨‚é„»  ă¨‚é„»  ă©č˝¨ëŞ­č…Śă©¨č˝¨ëŻ»č…Ś      ď•âź¸ě€¤ ă«€č˝¨éť»č…Š  ăŞč˝¨ă­č…žĺ€€ăĽˇ       ŕ§ŕ¦śŕ¦śŕ¦€ŕ¦śŕ¦€  á€€é„®   " ë€´é‹ľâ– &ă¬č˝¨ç–é‹ľá€€é„®) that I cannot use.

If I plug in an USB serial converter I get an other port but its name is empty.

The Desktop version works perfectly.

I can use the serial port in a UWP app.

Is there anybody how can use Serial port from .NET Core 2.0 on RPi3?

Answer (score 1):

*System.IO.Ports* does not support Windows IoT Core. On Windows IoT you have to use [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication) namespace to access serial ports. But it is available only in UWP context however not in .Net Core because of Windows OS policy. About this question, there have been several same discusses in StackOverflow and MSDN. But it is very frustrating that there is no any solution about this issue.

Comment: According to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18023  there should be some support already.
And somebody mentioned that here too: https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/issues/2

Comment: I don't think System.IO.Ports can work on Raspberry Pi with .net core, in fact i have tested on my Raspberry Pi 3. The issue #18023is still open.Have you test that? If  it works, please let me know and share your code. Thanks.